# HTTP2 and TLS with multiple socket connections

Tags: http, ssl, tls1.2, http2

I have used http2 in which I'm using 2 sockets(8090,8091)and establishing 4 connections i.e. multiplexing 2 connections on each socket.

I want to know about TLS. Whether we need TLS handshake only one time and then can continue and open another sockets also or we have to establish multiple TLS for each socket or for each connection?

Also can i use any cipher suite with TLS1.3?

Answer (score 0):

> ... we have to establish multiple TLS for each socket or for each connection?

TLS protects a single connection and thus the handshake need to be done for every new connection.

> Also can i use any cipher suite with TLS1.3?

No. There are specific ciphers defined for TLS 1.3. Specifically these are different from previous TLS versions.